# Add icons in between the collections in kendo template?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mobile, kendo-template

I have a kendo template which have the data source as Items which contains item1,item2,item3.

I need to add the icons in between the items not to the first item and last item in the Items dynamically.

Like this, item1 > item2 > item3.

Not like: > item1 > item2 > item3 >

Answer (score 1):

Just use some script within the template to test whether the icon should be added:

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="theTemplate">
  <div>
    # for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { # 
      <span>
        #= data[i].Item # 
        # if (i < data.length - 1){ 
            # &nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;  
        # } #
      </span>
    # } #
  </div>
</script>

var data = [
    {"Item":"ITEM1"},
    {"Item":"ITEM2"},
    {"Item":"ITEM3"},
    {"Item":"ITEM4"},
    {"Item":"ITEM5"}]

var submitTemplate = kendo.template($("#theTemplate").html());
$("#output").html(submitTemplate(data));
```

**[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/iPifo)**